# How to make IntelliJ reference source code in another module?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I have a typical project structure:

```
- root-dir (not a project)
 \- core-module (a gradle project)
 \- application (a gradle project)
```

Both `core-module` and `application` are imported into IntelliJ and kept on Auto Import. In `application`'s `build.gradle`, `core-module` is referenced as:

```
compile('my-group-id:core-module:0.2.0-SNAPSHOT')
```

where `0.2.0-SNAPSHOT` is the current version as declared in `core-module`'s `gradle.properties`.

In `application`, when I try to view a class from `core-module`, I'm brought to the source code in `core-module-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar`, instead of the corresponding source code in the `core-module` module.

I know I can manually add `core-module` as a module dependency in `application`, but next time anything in `application`'s `build.gradle` changes, auto import will overwrite that dependency.

**Is there any way to make IntelliJ recognize automatically that I'm trying to view a class from another module and go there instead of the downloaded sources jar?**

Furthermore, is there any way to make IntelliJ always prefer the `core-module` module over the dependency jar, not only for code viewing, but for building/running/debugging/etc.?

All the source files are in Kotlin, FWIW.

Comment: When you open the decompiled JAR class, it should have a link top right labeled "set source" or something similar. Unfortunately you might have to do that manually for each class.

Comment: @m0skit0 it does not open the decompiled class. It opens the source file in the sources jar, which is downloaded along with the binary jar itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Gradle's composite build. Gradle has composite builds https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/composite_builds.html that allow one to 'include' a build directly, rather than from a repository.

IntelliJ also supports this functionality. This was added in 2016.3.

Here's a webcast:https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/

In the Gradle tab, right-click on your application module. The menu will have a 'composite builds' option. On the dialog that appears, check the 'core-module' module and close.

Now, right-click on application module and do a 'refresh Gradle project'. I've found if I don't do this, the dependency doesn't get updated correctly.

To verify, look at the dependencies under the sourceSets. Instead of a version #, it will now look like a module dependency.

This provides many benefits. One is the navigation you were looking for. In addition, any changes made in core-module are immediately available, and used for the application.

Refactor a method in core-module that is used by application, and IntelliJ will refactor all usages.

Enjoy!

Comment: The IntelliJ part works out nicely. Thanks! Also thanks for letting me know about gradle's composite build. I'm not doing that part for now because at gradle level I'd like to still keep them separate. Fortunately the composite build config in IntelliJ appears to survive gradle refreshes. :-)

Comment: If you do want to do from CLI in gradle, you can do a build with the --include-build argument. In application dir, `./gradlew build --include-build ../core-module`. I use this all the time, and never use the explicit 'new build that's only to create a composite build' approach either.

And yes, the composite build setting remains until you explicitly turn it off.

Comment: very useful. Thanks.